# Google MAP API - Map marker Customize

Tags: google-maps, dictionary, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers, google-maps-sdk-ios

I am doing POC for the MAP api ( possibility of customization of google map marker )

my requirement is, i want add the button's (Add to Cart,Send Message) inside the marker and in the "Add To Cart" button click event i want to add the id of the marker to the Cart

is this possible call a button click event in the marker,please refer the attachment , POC Mock up reference [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gzan0.png)

Note : in my marker will have a more than one images ,i want to call the image button click event ,not an marker click event . assume i have a "Add To Cart" and "Send Message" and some other miscellanies images (rating and etc...) and i want to call the corresponding button click event and from the event i can do it with my code,i hope your understand my requirement. Is this possible.

Thanks In Advance!!! 
Siddik.K

Answer (score 0):

Yes  in google maps 3 you can draw a marker whit an image

```
image = '/yuor_path_to_img/your_image.png';

aMarker = new google.maps.Marker({
                    position: yourPosition
                    icon: image
                });
```

and then apply and a event listener  on this marker
 Insede the code of the listener you can call  the code you need for send the requeste to the server for save the value you need.

```
 google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function (event) {
                $.post( your_server_module, 
                        {marker_id: your_marker_id }, 
                );      
            });
```